# let local dns&name server to be reach from internet

Tags: internal-dns

I present the context: I have public fixed ip that it's set to my pfsense on the wan; I have internet on my lan; in my lan I have a local DNS server (ubuntu 22.04 with bind9 with ip 10.14.14.10) where I set the zone with an actual domain that I purchased (mm-it.ro); on the register (from where I purchased the domain). I set the domain mm-it.ro to point to my public IP (86.125.220.243); in pfsense, in general setup, I put the ip of the internal DNS server and in NAT&Rules it's set that everything from the wan on port 53 to point to my local DNS server ip.

Now: in LAN everything is working ; I can resolve in browser from any client from my lan: [www.mm-it.ro](http://www.mm-it.ro), mail.mm-it.ro. But from the internet I cannot reach the domain; I wait about 72 hours for propagation after I registered the public IP to that domain in the registerar site; nothing I change: a cannot ping to mm-it.ro or ns1.mm-it.ro; in mxtoolbox on dns lookup said
'DNS No Valid NameServers Responded' and after I select "find problems" it said `Unable to resolve "mm-it.ro" to an IP address`.

I don't know where the problem is: in pfsense or in my dns server setting, because in my local network, everything works? Below find my setting on may server

db.mm-it.ro (fw)

```
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns1.mm-it.ro. admin.mm-it.ro. (
                              6         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      ns1.mm-it.ro.
        IN      MX      10      mail.mm-it.ro.
ns1     IN      A       10.14.14.10
mm-it.ro.       IN      A       10.14.14.10
www     IN      A       10.14.14.11
mail    IN      A       10.14.14.12
```

---

db.10 (reverse)

```
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns1.mm-it.ro. admin.mm-it.ro. (
                              5         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      ns1.
10      IN      PTR     ns1.mm-it.ro.
10      IN      PTR     mm-it.ro.
11      IN      PTR     www.mm-it.ro.
12      IN      PTR     mail.mm-it.ro.
```

named.conf.local

```
zone "mm-it.ro" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.mm-it.ro";
};

zone "14.14.10.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        notify no;
        file "/etc/bind/db.10";
};
```

named.conf.options

```
acl ips {
        86.125.220.243;
        localhost;
        localnets;
        10.14.14.0/24;
};

options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";

        // If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
        // to talk to, you may need to fix the firewall to allow multiple
        // ports to talk.  See http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/800113

        // If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable
        // nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.
        // Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing
        // the all-0's placeholder.

        recursion yes;
        allow-query { ips; };
        allow-query-cache { ips; };
        allow-recursion { ips; };

        forwarders {
                8.8.8.8;
                8.8.4.4;
        };

        //========================================================================
        // If BIND logs error messages about the root key being expired,
        // you will need to update your keys.  See https://www.isc.org/bind-keys
        //========================================================================
        
        dnssec-validation auto;

        listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
        listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; 10.14.14.10; };
};
```

And in pfserver a have in rules the everyting that come from WAN on port 53 to be redirected to port 53 to my dns server on his ip 10.14.14.10. Also I disabled the services `Dns Resolver` and `DNS Forwarder`.

Please help me to point me to where the problem may be.

Comment: Your nameserver is ```ns1.mm-it.ro``` and where should someone get the IP of that? I was not able to get it. Check your registrar of your domain and enter the IP additionally to your hostname of the nameserver. Anyway I don't think it is a good idea to host services in your own if there are good alternatives.

Comment: Your registrar should have the option to set your nameserver by IP; make sure that your nameserver's IP is set to your public IP. Also be aware that your in-house nameserver cannot publish 10.x.x.x addresses to the internet and expect them to work; those addresses are defined as unroutable.

Answer (score 0):

While, as others have suggested, it is quite possible to have the DNS for your domain served from inside the domain given that the glue records or A records in a different domain are published, do not do this. Seriously.

DNS hosting is really cheap - most registrars give it away for free with registrations. Conversely running any sort of server on the internet requires a high level of skill and investment in hardening and ongoing monitoring/maintenance. There is a significant risk that your DNS server and potentially your domain could end being abused for very nefarious purposes without you having any knowledge about it until the police come knocking at your door.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the answers. I understand that i have to have also another zone setup for the external/internet (splitview). But i end up with installing bind in pfsense and made all the setup there and it's work for now. Thank you.